# Unable to login with Apple ID in iBooks Author

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect, ibooks-author

I have access to iTunes Connect with my Apple ID, but when I'm trying to sign in with the same Apple ID in iBooks Author it shows the following error:

> This Apple ID isn't associated with an iTunes Connect account.

I'm unable to understand the cause. Is it an issue with iBooks Author?

[image: iBooks Author screenshot of error message]

Comment: Have you contacted Apple about this?

Comment: I got the same error. Could you solve it now?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is misleading. The real issue is that you need a separate Apple ID to publish ebooks.
Here's what you should do:

1. Go to https://appleid.apple.com and create a new Apple ID. When
   asked for an email address, **don't re-use the one you entered for
   your primary iTunes account**. I made that mistake and my account
   became inaccessible. I had to call Apple support to finally fix the
   problem.
2. Download [iTunes Producer](http://itunespartner.apple.com/en/books/tools). Install and start it. Log in using your newly created Apple ID to your iTC account.
3. Create a new project in iTunes Producer. Add the cover image, the screenshots, and your ebook. Set the price and finally submit the book.